# How do i take a python ListProperty only Srings

Tags: python, kivy

I use a `ListProperty` and return:

```
['\xce\xbb\xce\xb9\xce\xb1\xcf\x83\xcf\x84\xce\xae \xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xce\xbf\xce\xbc\xce\xac\xcf\x84\xce\xb1',
 '\xcf\x83\xce\xbf\xcf\x85\xcf\x83\xce\xac\xce\xbc\xce\xb9',
 '\xcf\x84\xcf\x85\xcf\x81\xce\xaf']
```

I want to put them in one `ListItemLabel`, But it does not recognize them because they are in a `list`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: What does data type does `ListItemLabel` accepts

Comment: ListItemLabel accepts Strings

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to list by passing the strings one by one to list building function. To add them to your list make a loop and add them one by one to your listview.

```
list1=['\xce\xbb\xce\xb9\xce\xb1\xcf\x83\xcf\x84\xce\xae \xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xce\xbf\xce\xbc\xce\xac\xcf\x84\xce\xb1', '\xcf\x83\xce\xbf\xcf\x85\xcf\x83\xce\xac\xce\xbc\xce\xb9', '\xcf\x84\xcf\x85\xcf\x81\xce\xaf']
for option in list:
    #your code for adding option to your listview
```